# How to handle microservice UIs with Vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, single-page-application

We have about 12 microservices written with Spring Boot and Kotlin. Each of them has its own little Vaadin UI.

**How can we build a single entry point so that those individual UIs look like a single application?**

Note that we don't want to give up our microservice UI approach. It makes it easy for us to build new UIs very fast. But we want to give our users a better experience.

We have already tried to make an entry point by using `iframes` and including each microservice as an iframe. But it feels somehow wrong. But we are not UI-guys.

So are there any other approaches for us?

Comment: this depends on your requirements. Fore example, you could create common navigation and a theme that you use in all microservices. Navigation will be links anyway.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli the requirements are vague. We want to know what options we have (especially what Vaadin supports), so that we can decide whats feasible.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use Vaadin or any other framework. The question is if you simply want to integrate multiple applications that have the same styling with links (that's what Amazon does) or if you want to have kind of a Microfrontend-approach. https://github.com/Artur-/iot

Comment: @SimonMartinelli so you say there are two options: (1) integration with links (this would mean using iframes, right?) or (2) a microfrontend-approch. But judging from the GitHub link you shared, approach 2 would mean to integrate the UIs during build time. Am I correct?

Comment: 1) is not with Iframes but simply separate applications. 2 is a build time microfrontend approach. Unfortunately currently there is no common sense how to do microfrontend

Comment: You could also checkout https://scs-architecture.org/ and a German podcast series https://www.innoq.com/de/podcast/025-scs-frontend-integration/transcript/